# Uncaught Type Error: Cannot call method 'push' undefined in jquery-1.5.1.min.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am getting **error message**

```
Uncaught Type Error: Cannot call method 'push' undefined in jquery-1.5.1.min.js
```

here is the **code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  setDrawingCanvasCoords();  
  js_c_drawing = new fabric.Canvas('c_drawing');  
  js_c_drawing.calcOffset();  
  fabric.instances.push(js_c_drawing);  
});
```

What am I doing wrong in above code can anyone please help me

Comment: Didn't you ask this question just a few minutes ago? Still, and my comment then is as it will be now. Is `fabric.instances` a NOT NULL/UNDEFINED Array? Else, initialize it.

Comment: yeah I repost question so that it should in clear way @limelights
i already initialise in $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: In Fabric.js there isn't such a thing called 
`instances` on the fabric object. If you want to add stuff to the canvas created by Fabric use `.add()` but on the `js_c_drawing` object.

Comment: @limelights i used .add() but in another index from der i render in to main script function

Comment: Okay, but still, `instances` doesn't exist on the fabric object so no matter how hard you try you wont get it by default.

Comment: So wat's ur suggestion and i tried to remove instances but the error is still existing and it is displaying fabric.object is undefined sumding like dis @limelights

Comment: @Geetha: Don't re-post questions, but [edit] them.

Comment: @Bergi ya next time I wont repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this checking:

```
 if( typeof fabric.instances != "undefined" )  fabric.instances.push(js_c_drawing);
```

Comment: the error is not coming but when i tried to drag and resize the shape the error is displaying again @Prakash GPz

Answer (score 1):

This is the line with the error.

```
fabric.instances.push(js_c_drawing);
```

The error is most likely:

```
Uncaught Type Error: Cannot call method 'push' OF undefined
```

It is telling you that `fabric.instances` does not exist. `Array.prototype.push` is probably the method you are trying to call. This `pushes` and element to the end of an array. It is equivalent to doing:

```
var a = [] // or new Array;
a[a.length] = 5; // the length property will automatically adjust itself.
```

Without the full code, we cannot help more. Set up a jsFiddle if you need more help.

Comment: when i check the error in console it displaying near jquery-1.5.1.min.js